# Mac ignores "Display login window as" setting

Tags: macos, login-screen

My Mac mini ignores the "Display login window as" setting. I have it set to "Name and password" but it still displays a "List of users" whenever it reboots.

It is a multi-boot setup. Does OS X for some reason store this setting in the vnram?

Update: When I log out it shows name and password field. But when it comes back from a reboot it shows the list of users instead.

Comment: Didn't occur to me to try. Will come back.

Comment: Do you have any configuration profiles installed?

Comment: What are configuration profiles?

Comment: System Preferences → Profiles, [example](http://f.cl.ly/items/3c1t2e3g2v3c310Q2e3v/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-23%20at%2017.41.18.png)

Comment: No profiles installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have FileVault 2 turned on? The FileVault 2 login screen isn't able to show username and password blanks; only names and icons.

Comment: But can you add a source?

Comment: Yes, I would love to see a source for this answer, which is basically just saying that it is how it was designed. I would disagree. Firstly, if username/password wasn't an option when FileVault was enabled they would grey it out. Also, as the OP said, when you change the setting and log out, you get the username/password login option. You can log in and log out multiple times and that option remains. But if you reboot it reverts back to showing the list of users. The problem is awfully similar to this problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5526860?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: More digging: it looks like this behavior has been around for a while and is definitely related to FileVault. http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1215840 What is even more annoying is that all the other options can be changed, just not this one. Unbelievable that this hasn't been rectified so far and very unlike Apple.

Comment: OK, found this informative link: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3201161 About half way down there is a comment by a person named Peter Link, who doesn't provide any credentials but does put forth a very detailed and convincing explanation as to why OS X behaves this way when Filevault is enabled. I still find it strange that Apple wouldn't acknowledge this limitation by greying out the "name and password" option when Filevault is enabled, but whatever. I did read that the login screen is getting revamped in Yosemite, so here's hoping they address this minor, yet annoying issue.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is minor. In my company we use FileVault2, and we need to use domain users to log in the machines, which is impossible due to this issue! >_< At least now I know why this is happening, so thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

basically, login as user displayed, hit the logout button, it should display the user/password blanks, login as the domain user, setup the mobile user, and logout again, user will now show up in the menu.