# Make mac become more server

Tags: terminal, ssh, ui

Take another system I use (for example CentOS).
I use the following code to make it become server.

```
# No GUI
systemctl set-default multi-user.target

# Enable SSH
sudo systemctl start sshd
```

It has two big advantages.

1. doesn't sleep
2. saves power

Can I do something similar in OS X?

P.S.  I know how to make it become available by other computer with ssh. I just want OS X not show any desktop environment just the cli.

P.S.2  The link [Is there console mode in Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/is-there-console-mode-in-mac-os-x) didn't work for me in Ei captain, since I select name and password in system preference, and restart. I still get `list of user`(icon and username). The reason is `filevault`. 
If I follow what the link said, I need to turn `filevault` off. That is not I want. See link [Mac ignores "Display login window as" setting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114612/mac-ignores-display-login-window-as-setting)

Then I try to log out the current user and is able to use the function of `name and password`. when I use `>console`， I can ssh to it

Comment: I am sorry, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: Why does it save power?

Comment: I have flagged this question as 'very low quality' as it is unclear for me what the question is.

Comment: A computer  doesn't become a server because the computer doesn't "go to sleep" and/or "saves power."  It is a server because it **serves** something; time, files, web pages, boot environments, etc.  What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: @CousinCocaine The main purpose is when I start mac, I don't want gui just command line shows

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn OS X, the *Client* version, in to a **Server** then you need to install [OS X Server](http://www.apple.com/osx/server/) and configure it to meet your needs.

Add **OS X Server** to your Mac from the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id883878097) for just $19.99.